# Error occurs when applying vuetify and vue-loader together in vue-cli environment

Tags: vue.js, webpack, markdown, vuetify.js, vue-loader

**My goal**

I made my webpage with vue-cli and vuetify, and I tried to add vue-markdown-loader.

**Actual results**

But error occured After I add source about vue-loader in vue.config.js

This is error message.

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-navigation-drawer> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
...
```

This is my vue.config.js source

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rule('md')
    .test(/\.md/)
    .use('vue-loader')
    .loader('vue-loader')
  }
}
```

**What I tried**

So, I made new simple project to test like next.

```
vue create test-vuetify
cd test-vuetify
vue add vuetify
```

and add same settings on vue.config.js

```
chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rule('md')
        .test(/\.md/)
        .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
      }
```

It also occur same error

How can I add vue-loader about markdown file and use vuetify together?

I saw semilar case at vuetify-loader github, and vue-markdown-loader github.

- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/106
- https://github.com/QingWei-Li/vue-markdown-loader/issues/64

But I can't find answer. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please share it with me.

**version of modules**

This is version of my modules

```
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vuetify": "^2.2.11",
"vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
```

Comment: I'd say it's more than likely that Vuetify bug you've listed. There's a PR somebody has created so you could always try out their fork. FYI, I'd change the webpack rule test to `/\.md$/`

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'll fix webpack rule test as you told me. And I modified the vuetify module and tested it, but I couldn't find the answer